# Getting dom elements from the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, onclick, dom-events

Let's say I have the
URL:-`www.example.com`

In that page I have dom element `<a>` .
Now if want to click that pro-grammatically I will do  `document.getElementById('#link')[0].click()`.

The problem here is I have multiple url's , I want to write a js program so that it will go the suggested web page and get the `domElement` to click that

MY idea here is I will write all the url's in an array, and I will loop that array to get the dom element of that particular web page (specified in url).

Does anybody have any idea of getting dom elements by url?

Comment: `getElementByTagNames` That will not work. Spelling matters in programming. Also, better to use `querySelector` if you want to select only a single element.

Comment: `js program so that it will go the suggested webpage and get the domElement to click that` - how do you propose the "js program" will be able to "go to the suggested webpage" .. I take it this is a nodejs question, not a question about code in a browser - because JS in a browser can't "go" somewhere

Comment: `getElementByTagNames` is not a function, the right one is `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: This would only work as a Bookmarklet or userscript - you cannot execute javascript from a URL in another page

Comment: @CertainPerformance see the solution.

Comment: @JaromandaX see the solution

Comment: @YousafHassan see the solution

Comment: @mplungjan see the solution..

Comment: Your solution as written, does not explain what you wanted to do. Please post more details or just delete the question since it does not make any sense to other people than you currently

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved my issues by copying all the multiple links in an array a[];
and  i have loaded the iframe based on the links in an array, and therefore got the dom elements from the iframe

Comment: you talk of iframe and dom ... yet you tagged the question `nodejs`